# extracting tags from xml using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml

I have an XML in the following format:

```html
<lfm status="ok">
<artisttracks user="RJ" artist="shakira" page="1" perPage="50" totalPages="0" total="0">
<track>
<artist mbid="bf24ca37-25f4-4e34-9aec-460b94364cfc">Shakira</artist>
<name>Can't Remember to Forget You</name>
<streamable>0</streamable>
<mbid/>
<album mbid="">Shakira. (Deluxe Version)</album>
<url>
https://www.last.fm/music/Shakira/_/Can%27t+Remember+to+Forget+You
</url>
<image size="small">
https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/6f52cd9bdf564954c9df5a574db26cc4.png
</image>
<image size="medium">
https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/6f52cd9bdf564954c9df5a574db26cc4.png
</image>
<image size="large">
https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/6f52cd9bdf564954c9df5a574db26cc4.png
</image>
<image size="extralarge">
https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/6f52cd9bdf564954c9df5a574db26cc4.png
</image>
<date uts="1472405290">28 Aug 2016, 17:28</date>
</track>
```

How do I extract the track names using ng-repeat?
I tried the following

```
<table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="track in model.tracks">
    <tr ng-repeat="name in model.artisttrack">
        <td>
            {{track.name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It is displaying the entire xml file.

Comment: you need to convert the XML data into JSON first

Comment: Yes, I solved it by changing the format.

Answer (score 0):

All modern browsers have a built-in XML parser that can convert text into an XML DOM object.

```
var text, parser, xmlDoc;

text = "<bookstore><book>" +
    "<title>Everyday Italian</title>" +
    "<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>" +
    "<year>2005</year>" +
    "</book></bookstore>";

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Also, take a look at [x2js](https://github.com/abdmob/x2js)

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp)